# Connect M-series Mac to 4k display

Tags: mac, display, 4k

I have a new M2 MacBook Air and a Philips 279P1/27 4k monitor. They don't get along. I use a USB-C to USB-C cable that came with the monitor.

I also have a PC for work and I use the monitor for both. The monitor works great with the PC.

Initially, the Mac did not recognize the monitor. They do connect if I first disconnect the power adapter from the Mac, then connect the Mac to the monitor, then re-connect the power to the Mac. Maybe the Mac needs to try to get powered by the monitor for it to look for a video connection?

Even with that, the display often flickers.

[This article](https://www.howtogeek.com/805459/mac-flickering-external-screen/) offers some tips. The most important thing is probably the power cycling described above. Additionally, the article suggests,

- using a fixed refresh rate
- checking dongles
- checking monitor settings for things like variable refresh rate and black frame insertion
- updating monitor firmware
- using DisplayPort

I'm using a fixed refresh rate and the monitor settings are fine. The monitor does not have upgradable firmware.

1. How do I reduce the flickering?
2. Why does this happen? Based on my [reading](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-pro-m1-external-screen-flickering.2325279/), it seems that this is a widespread problem with 4k monitors for the past couple of years, possibly tied to a bug in the OS. What's the fundamental issue and is progress on it likely?

I do not know why this doesn't just work right.

Answer (score -1):

As I said in the question, the connection works if I disconnect the power adapter and then make the USB-C connection. Disconnecting and reconnecting sometimes resolves the flickering.

Comment: It just flickered. :-(

Comment: Pls consider expanding your answer so that one can still figure it out even if the link you have provided is broken or the article is changed?